# AngularJS async validation makes error messages flicker

Tags: angularjs

I am using a simple async validator to check the existance of a username with a directive like this

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.directive('usernameAvailableValidator', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.usernameAvailable = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                return $http.get('/api/check-availability?username=' + value)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.userFound) {
                            return $q.reject();
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

This works. The only problem is that the error and success messages that I display with ng-if flickers while I type. I don't know how to solve this problem. And instead of showing you more code I have uploaded the form to demonstrate the flickering.

I have one form without the async validation that does not flicker at all.

And one form with async validation that makes the messages flicker.

The form that does not flicker can be found here:

http://itexpert.no/register2

Here if you try to type in a username like "Alexander", and then blur, and then backspace all the way to nothing and then write "Alexander" again you will see that the messages show up as they are supposed to. They do not flicker. This is without the async validation.

Now if you try the same thing as above on this form with async validation you will see what I mean by the messages flickering.

http://itexpert.no/register

This I find to be very frustrating but I completely hit the wall here and I don't know how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Angular is updating model as user type, so many requests are being made using the async validator.

Use `ng-model-options` directive with your async validator input.

`ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`

This way async calls will only be made when you leave input.

The other option is to use a debounce effect

`ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"`

This options tells to update model only after 1 second delay.

Please see the documentation on `ng-model-options` https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions